# How to save button value to databse in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to create my first django app - sports predictions game. 
 
I want user to select from three possible results using 3 buttons (images) which pass 3 different values to the db: 
1 - home team wins 
0 - draw 
 
2 - away team wins

I am able to save data using forms when I type something into it, but **how do I pass value of these buttons to my database?**

code on my game.html:

```
{% csrf_token %}

{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value = 1>
<input type="submit" value = 0>
<input type="submit" value = 2> </form>
```

and my view:

```
def game(request, Game_id):
    thisgame = get_object_or_404(Game, pk=Game_id)
    nextgame = int(thisgame.id)+1
    template = loader.get_template('polls/game.html')
    form = NewBetForm(request.POST or None)
    current_user = request.user

    allgames = Game.objects.all()
    betchoices = BetChoice.objects.all()

    context = { 'thisgame': thisgame,
                'nextgame': nextgame,
                'form': form,
                'current_user': current_user,
                'betchoices': betchoices,}

    if form.is_valid():
        bet = form.save(commit=False)
        bet.gameid = Game.objects.get(id=Game_id)
        bet.userid_id = current_user.id
        bet.save()
    else:
        print (form.errors)
```

and my form:

```
class NewBetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = GameBet
        fields = ['bet']
```

and the error I get is `Bet - this field is required`

Thank you for all ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set name for it like :

```
<input type="submit" name="send1" value ="1">
```

**Note** : you should value part like  `value ="1"`

and in `views.py`:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
      if request.POST["send1"] == "1":
            //do some thing
      elif request.POST["send1"] == "2":
             //do domthing
      else://request.POST["send1"] == "3"
             //do something
```

i hope it will help you :)

Comment: Hi @Snip77 , thank you for your answer. I need 3 buttons so should I name each one differently? Right now I got `MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))` with local vars:
`key  - 'send1'
self  {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': code',
 'send3': '3'}`

Comment: yes you should call them diffrent.beacuse you want to detect button in server side.call then like : 1, 2 and 3.in server side you need to know button with which name clicked.if you have an other problem,tell me,maybe i can answer :)

Comment: I think I'm still missing something here. Do I need the `"if form is valid()"` part in this approach? Right now I have the following but it does nothing:

`if request.method == 'POST':
  if request.POST["bet"] == 1:
   if form.is_valid():
    bet = form.save(commit=False)
    bet.gameid = Game.objects.get(id=Game_id)
    bet.userid_id = current_user.id
    bet.save()
   else:
    print (form.errors)`

Comment: if you have default django login or default django sign up you don't need to use **if form is valid()** but in other cases you need it(better to use).(whe you add mor field to sign up for you need too use it too :) )

Answer (score 0):

As with any other type of form field, a submit button needs a `name` attribute before it will send any data to the backend. From there, you can just pick up its value via `request.POST['whatever_the_name_is']` and assign it to your newly created object - or, if you use the name that is already a field in the form, it will be assigned automatically.